# Moved Magento store from one domain to another (same host) and now admin inputs not saving

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

I've just come across a weird, extremely frustrating issue which I've now wasted two hours trying to get to the bottom of...

I've just copied a new Magento store from one domain to another on the same server. There is currently the website on the old domain and it is duplicated on the new domain.

- Base URL's updated.
- Database credentials updated.
- Cache cleared.
- Sessions cleared.
- Server tmp directory cleared.
- The only other thing I had to do was change the redirect to base config in the database from 1 to 0 to get rid of the redirect loop.

Everything works perfectly fine on the old domain. All functionality is as expected with no errors in the logs.

On the new domain however, I cannot make any changes from the Magento admin panel. Nothing saves despite the 'changes made successfully' notification:-

- None of the checkboxes are recognised if I try to bulk delete/edit.
- None of the dropdown are recognised.
- I can click on links and perform actions (i.e reindex an individual index).

There are no errors in the log. There are no errors in the browser console.

I really have no idea how the site works fine on one domain and not on another yet I have no errors anywhere (and logging is working as I forced errors to check this).

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a JS issue - have you looked at the JS error console in your browser? Have you checked the net output in your browser to confirm no assets are 404'ing?

Comment: There were no errors in console at all no. Oh man. Just figured what the issue was. Client set up the domain in Plesk on server and left the server config as default no www from within Plesk. When I update the base URL with the www prefix, the two conflict and was causing some sort of weird redirect on the save actions button. *Sigh...

Comment: Type your answer in below and mark it as the accepted answer. It will help the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We eventually identified the cause of this issue.

The client had created the domain themselves on their server within the Plesk panel and had created the domain to use `domain.tld` instead of `www.domain.tld` or leaving as `none` (best practice). When we tried to migrate the site over to `www.domain.com` using the base URL, this was causing some sort of weird redirect on the save actions button (probably in the form of a 'behind the scenes' redirect loop).